# What is preferred way to implement uniq or uniqBy filter for Array/List?

Tags: purescript

There seems no straight implementing uniq or uniqBy filter for Array/List

`["val1", "val2", "val1"]` -> `["val1", "val2"]`

`["key1" /\ 1, "key2" /\ 10, "key1" /\ 20]` -> `["key1" /\ 1, "key2" /\ 10]`

There can be many ways of doing this, but what is the preferred/better way to in terms of performance/simplicity?

Comment: Did you mean [`nub`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-arrays/5.3.1/docs/Data.Array#v:nub)?

Comment: hah, thanks, didn't notice that standard one. (